# invoking block in array with parameters

Tags: ios, arrays, objective-c-blocks

I've seen the answer about invoking a block that is stored in an array, but I can't get it to work with parameters.

I store the array an a part of an object, then when it's in a method, I want to invoke it, however, I need parameters.

Also, is there any limit to the parameters.

Lastly, I'd rather not use the extra storage to the variable, so invoking directly while in the array would be better.

```
__block int x = 123; //  x lives in block storage
void (^printXAndY)(int) = ^(int y) {
    x = x + y;
    NSLog(@"X and Y: %d %d\n", x, y);
};

self.blocks = @[printXAndY];
printXAndY(10); // this works

    void(^block)(void) = self.blocks[0];
    block(); // this works
    block(10); // this doesn't work
    [self.blocks[0] invoke ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
void(^block)(void) = self.blocks[0];
```

You are declaring 'block' to take no parameters and return nothing. If you want the block to take a parameter, you need to declare it like this:

```
void(^block)(int) = self.blocks[0];
```

Note that `block();` will no longer work.  And when you declared the block incorrectly, that line was undefined behavior.

Comment: That's the ticket, thanks.  I feel a bit stupid for not seeing that.